# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined. I have tried to reinstall electron as well

Tags: javascript, electron

I am not able to remove an error mentioned:

> "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined**"

I have tried to reinstall electron as well but still getting the same error.

```
 const electron = require('electron');
 const {BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron');
 var app = electron.app;
 const conn = require('mysql');
 const path = require('path');
 const url = require('url');
 var mainWindow;
 app.on('ready', function () {
     mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1024, height: 768, 
     backgroundcolor: 'black' });
        mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: 'dashboard.html',
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
       }));
     mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
     mainWindow.setProgressBar(1);
});
```

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: elctron file resides in the same folder?

Comment: app.on() here is an error...

Comment: yes the electron is installed in my app

Comment: is it included in package.json file? just check

Answer (score -2):

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" 
>   This means 'app' object has not been loaded properly from 'electron' module and the 'app.on()' method on 8th line, it has been called on undefined object 'app'.

Please try these possible solutions.

1. Replace

   ```
   const electron = require('electron');
   const {BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron');
   var app = electron.app;
   ```

   with

   ```
   var app = require('electron').app;
   const {BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron');
   ```
2. In Package.json file edit/add this line specifying the starting point for an application.

   ```
    "script":{"start": "electron ."}
   ```

edit:

May be you have the npm electron module installed somewhere in your system(globally), it overrides the builtin electron module. You can find out the path of it by logging out

```
 require.resolve('electron').
```

Comment: You didn't really add anything. The alternative you should've provided was that he can destructure everything out of the same `require` statement: `app`, ``BrowserWindow`` and ``Menu``.

Comment: destructuring every module out of same require object is not the issue here (It works the same).! I just merged those two expressions into one by chaining it. Also i mentioned it as the 'possible solutions' because the 2nd point had solved my issue in the past.

Comment: You're not even chaining it properly; requiring `electron` twice in a row.  And Electron is a development dependency, it would prioritise the one in `node_modules` then `global`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. (Y)